# how can i parse an xml / html file into a json file through symfony or nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular, symfony

I am preparing a new project and I will run external tools so that it gives a result xml / html file but no json I want to take the results xml / html or any format into a json file to use it.

how can i parser them using **symfony** or **nodejs**.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check [Serializer Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html)

Comment: serializer supports entities not files @jakmen